# Extracting of digital data from logs

Tags: bash, shell

I have workdir consisted of 10 sub dirs in each of which there is some relevant log.log consisting of a huge data.

Using `tail -n 3 log.log`, I obtain something like:

```
               (Mnbf/s)   (GFlops)   (ns/day)  (hour/ns)
Performance:   1978.319    102.192     21.487      1.117
Finished mdrun on node 0 Tue Mar 15 16:23:03 2016
```

from which only the 21.487 digit is important.

Question: What combination of the bash shell commands will be useful to extract from that data only the digit 21.487 and put it into the specified log?

Then I'm going to put this command in a loop to process such data from 10 independent runs, and calculate the average from them.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Could you edit your post to avoid bad syntax, format your message, and explain better (like, what is this 2- applying the tail -n 3 log.log line) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk`:

```
tail -n2 file | awk 'NR==1{print $4}'
```

You can use that together with `find` like this:

```
find . -name 'log.log' -exec bash -c 'tail -n2 "$1" | awk "NR==1{print $4}"' - "{}" \;
```

I'm assuming you are in that folder. Otherwise replace `.` by `/path/to/folder`